# Delete data from table master have relationship many to many

Tags: database, laravel

i'am using laravel framework for backend.

i have 4 tables :

**1. Product**

**2. Product_colors**

**3. Images**

**4. Image_product_color**

I want to delete the data that is on table : Images and `Image_product_color`
went i try to delete this data, i can deleted it from `image_product_color` but i cant delete data from table Images. What its the problem?

here is my database schema :

**1. Products**

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('product_code')->unique();
  $table->text('name');
  $table->text('slug');
  $table->bigInteger('base_price');
  $table->integer('weight')->nullable();
  $table->text('description')->nullable();
  $table->smallInteger('status')->default(0);
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

**2. Product_colors**

```php
Schema::create('product_colors', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->string('base_color');
      $table->string('original_color');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**3. Images**

```php
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->binary('image');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**4. Image_product_color**

```php
Schema::create('image_product_color', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('product_color_id')->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('product_color_id')->references('id')->on('product_colors')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

**MODEL :**

ProductColor

```php
class ProductColor extends Model
{
  protected $fillable=[
    'product_id','base_color','original_color'
  ];

  public function products()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'product_id');
  }
  public function images()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class);
  }

  public function productsizes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(ProductSize::class);
  }

}
```

**Image**

```php
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
      'image'
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
    public function productcolors()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(ProductColor::class);
    }
}
```

iam using eloquent method:

here is my code :

```php
  $productcolor = ProductColor::findOrFail($id);
        $total_product_variant = Productcolor::where('product_id',$productcolor->product_id)->get();
        if (count($total_product_variant) === 1) {
          Product::destroy($productcolor->product_id);
        }
        if (count($productcolor->images) > 0) {
          foreach ($productcolor->images as $images) {
              $url = public_path().'/upload/products/'.$images->image;
              if (file_exists($url)) {
                unlink($url);
                $productcolor->images()->detach($images->id);
                Image::destroy($images->id);
                // Image::delete($images->id);
              }else {
                $productcolor->images()->detach($images->id);
                Image::destroy($images->id);
                // Image::delete($images->id);
              }
          }
        }

        ProductColor::destroy($id);
        return response()->json([
          'status'=>'success'
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in entering id images : `Image::destroy($images->id);`  in the pivot table you name the image id with image_id `$table->integer('image_id')->unsigned();`

then in this section: `Image::destroy($images->id);` should be : `Image::destroy($images->image_id);`

if u are using `$images->id`  then you delete the wrong data